# design implementation regarding factory method in java

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, factory-pattern

I have a design question to ask.  I so far have not written any code, just thinking about how to implement at this point.  I have an object of type A and it contains an object of type B.  I would like B to define a category of objects (Interface or abstract class?).  I then have an xml file that defines the sub-type that B should be.  For instance, if B is an interface named Driveable, then "car" or "truck" might be defined in the xml as the Drivable object needed for type A.

What I was thinking of doing is making B an interface and then creating a static factory class that has a factory method to determine what sub-type B should be given an xml file.  So my first question is would this be the best way to approach the problem?  Would it be better to use an abstract class instead of an interface or is it mainly just personal preference?

Second, if I do go with an interface, then inside my factory method would I just do:

```
B createB(File f){
    ...
    String type = ...
    if(type.equals("car"))
        return new CarType();
    else if(type.equals("truck"))
        return new TruckType();
    ...
    return null;
}
```

So every time I add a new B sub-type, I would need to add another if statement to this method.  Is there a better way to do this so all I would have to do is create a new B sub-type and then update my xml and not update the factory method?  I essentially dont want to hard code in the types of B into my factory method.  If what I have above is pretty standard protocol with factory methods, then I can deal with doing it that way, just doesnt quite seem right.

Comment: You need AbstractFactory Pattern for that case. Search for it on Google. You will get a link to Wikipedia, which explains what it is.

Comment: I only have one abstract product though (type B).  I would then need to create a new concrete factory for every new sub-type of B.  And at some point I would need to decide which concrete factory to use.  Seems like it would present the same "problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Growing off of carnold's example, your could create a map in your Factory Class that maps between the text in the xml and the corresponding java class.

```
private final static Map<String, Class> typeMap;

static {
   typeMap = new HashMap<String, Class>();
   typeMap.put("car", CarType.class); 
   typeMap.put("truck", TruckType.class);
}
```

and then in your method:

```
B createB(File f){
    ...
    String type = ...
    Class clazz = typemap.get(type);
    if (clazz == null){
        return null;
    }

    B newB = clazz.getConstructor(/*arg types*/).newInstance(/*args*/);
    return newB;
}
```

Slightly easier to maintain than the if/else, but still have to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks! After posting I was thinking of doing that.  There may not be a way to completely eliminate maintenance unless I explicitly state the class name in the xml as carnold suggested.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is define in xml the actuall classname that you want the B impls to be and then use the generic class constructor like this (missing error handling):

```
String bimplClassname = //read from xml
Class bimplClass = Class.forName(bimplClassname);
B newB = bimplClass.getConstructor(/*arg types*/).newInstance(/*args*/);
```

Comment: What if my xml did not state the class name directly?  Line in my example, I have "car" written in my xml, but my class name is "CarType".  Would I still be able to do this?

Comment: As long as you can programatically convert the text in the xml into an actual java classname

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what triggers the creation of your objects. If it is some text that triggers the creation, then your existing code is fine for a small application. You could also choose a dependency injection framework like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).

Also, note that for comparing strings, you should use the `.equals` method, not == as shown in your code.

Comment: Ha yeah, def meant to use .equals().  Currently I only have 2 sub-types of B and those are the only types I am going to be using in the foreseeable future.  Yeah, basically the xml is used primarily when the program first starts up and is used to house initial parameters for the program.  The parameter to define the sub-type of B will always be a string.  I dont know if I want to go into the trouble of figuring out something like Guice just for an application this small but definitely will look into it.